# multiple x values spotfire

Tags: scatter-plot, spotfire

I am currently trying to adapt an excel dashboard I created a few years back into spotfire. The data previously fit onto one page, but this year the number of metrics has doubled and I thought it would be a good opportunity to try spotfire.

The current dashboard has a number of scatter plot charts showing the values from a range of cells (rank 1-5). Overlaid is another scatter plot that shows the groups results.

I have found it easy enough to run the scatter plot in Excel based on a range of data, but as of right now I am stumped on how to choose a range of values for my spotfire scatters.

[Here is an example (in excel)](http://www.nocobe.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/sample-excel.xlsx)  of what I am trying to accomplish. The data example is how my data is currently setup.

Would you have any tips on how I may be able to produce a similar chart in Spotfire?

Comment: Is it possible for you to attach the excel you are trying to port to spotfire?

Comment: I was able to upload the file to my site. I have added the link into the body of my question. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'range of cells'? Which cells from you example file should be plotted (and against what)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a  `Document.Properties` with all the values you want. Then create a slider in a text area with this document properties. You will be able to select a range of values with this slider.

To use your range in a scatter plot, on the axis you want, right click and `custom expression` then write something like `$(my_docproperty)`.

Hope it will a solution to your problem !